# How to make Google Sheets draw trends in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-charts-trendlines

I have a graph on Google Sheets (based on two columns) that plots many points (think of it like the stock market):

[image]

I would like the graph to not show the micro data and instead show trends.. something like this:

[image]

ideas?

Comment: Please checkout [Add & edit a trendline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6075154?hl=en). If you need further details create a demo spreasheet including the data to create the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SMA](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/simple-moving-average-in-google-sheets/) (Simple moving average). It works as follow

- Take W points back (e.g. 3, 5 or 10, that's your window size) and do an average for them. This will create a new point
- Use those newly created points to plot your line.

NOTE: at the end you'll have N-W+1 points where N is original number of points and W is your window size

Here is an example google sheet for [Milk production per pound per month](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iDZiFUzWsVP-mr-ae0iaffidr5WL9KsQ3_tdqOfU5aY/edit?usp=sharing) with smoothing via a window 3 and window 10 and the trend line (straight line)

[image]